# how to pass a string array into actionresult

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a variable that is a string[] parameter. I've tried to push values in the actionresult and have yet to match the string[] parameter. So my ajax:

```
    var panels = [];
    $('input.checkone').each(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var inputCheck = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(6) a').text();
            panels.push(inputCheck);
        }
    });
    var data = { panels: panels };
    $.ajax({
      url: "/main/sub",
      data: data,
    }).etc...
```

So panels looks like panels: Array[1] 0:'test',
and it goes to my controller:

```
public ActionResult sub(string[] panels)
{
 //content 
}
```

Currently the panels is going through like {string[1]}. I'm not sure why my strings aren't being passed in correctly and its being passed like {string[1]}.

Comment: what about using `innerHTML` instead of `text`?

Comment: it seems like its passing ok in the jQuery, it gets the text, but when I pass it to my controller it gets replaced with {string[1]}

Comment: okay what about `var data = { 'panels': panels };`

Comment: yeah that did the exact same thing

Comment: Did you try adding `contentType: "application/json"`?

Comment: `data : JSON.stringify({
      panels: data
   }),`

Comment: yeah i tried that earlier, didnt work

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
        var url = 'http://my-address/';
        var array = ["hello", "world"];
        $.post(url, $.param({ data: array }, true), function (result) {
            $('#MyDiv').html(result);                
        }); 



public ActionResult sub(List<string> data)
{
 //content 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell jQuery to serialize your parameters in the traditional way, which is not the default anymore since jQuery 3.0.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/main/sub",
    data: data,
    traditional: true
})
```